# impossible to excute a intellij idea beacuse of crack

Tags: intellij-idea

When starting the program through the terminal, i get this error message

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /Users/thebettertech/dev/crack/JetbrainsCrack-3.1-release-enc.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

That folder and file don't exist.
I have a license. I don't know why they're sending this message to me.

Comment: Try to delete all [IDE directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) and reinstall the IDE from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download .

Comment: Already tried several times.. 
Is there any other way to completely delete it?